# How to crawl youtube shorts title, views, # of subscribers in selenium python

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

In this youtube webpage (https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=birds+fly), I'd like to scrape (1) youtube shorts title, (2) views, (3) # of subscribers, (4) number of shorts in selenium python.

If I manually search on youtube,
number of shorts is 6.

Could you help me write a selenium python?

Thanks in advance for your help.

I tried:

```
!pip install selenium==4.1.5
!pip install webdriver_manager
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service #chromedriver 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager #chromedriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()) 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=birds+fly')

#get the elements
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.style-scope.yt-horizontal-list-renderer[id="items"]')

#print the count of elements
print(len(elements))`
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more short videos in the reel than just 6. If you want just those 6 using selenium is a waste and request+bs4 is more than enough. However, with selenium you can click on right_button and load more videos and scrap them.
I couldn't find number of subscribers but for title and number_of_views, you can do like this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

# loading driver is different in your code, you can keep that with required imports
url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=birds+fly" 
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get(url)

# ActionChains for scrolling to element
actions = ActionChains(driver)

# for only one Shorts horizontal list
reel = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'yt-horizontal-list-renderer')))

# scroll to first Shorts
actions.move_to_element(reel).perform()
right_button = WebDriverWait(reel, timeout=3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#right-arrow > ytd-button-renderer')))

# clicking right-button till all shorts load in the reel/browser/document
while not reel.get_attribute('at-end') == '':
    # You may want to wait/delay and/or 'move to element' if driver doesn't find right_button
    # time.sleep(0.25)
    # actions.move_to_element(right_button)
    right_button.click()

# working on each item/short_video in reel
items = reel.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#items > ytd-reel-item-renderer')
num_of_items = len(items)
for item in items:
    title = item.find_element(By.ID, 'video-title').get_attribute('innerText')
    views = item.find_element(By.ID, 'metadata').get_attribute('innerText')
    print("Title:", title)
    print("Views:", views)

print("\nNumber of shorts:", num_of_items)
input()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Title: The Fastest Flying Bird In The World #shorts #birds #animals
Views: 134K views
Title: Why do birds fly in V shape
Views: 8.8K views
Title: Budgie bhaag gya?  Parrot Free fly training #freefly #budgies #shorts #birds #staytuned
Views: 1.4M views
Title: Kiwi | The Cute Flightless Bird
Views: 1.3M views
Title: Why birds fly in "V-Shape" - By Kishor Singh #shorts
Views: 2.6M views
Title: Slow-Mo Bird
Views: 915K views
Title: Birds flying high you know (how i feel) #Shorts
Views: 4.9K views
Title: Free flying parrots - indoor recall
Views: 93K views
Title: Can Birds Fly Backwards? | BYJU's Mistaken Science #shorts
Views: 17K views
Title: bird stops in mid-air (subhanAllah)
Views: 23K views
Title: The Only Bird That Can Fly Backwards
Views: 22K views
Title: Why birds fly.... #shorts #subscribe #facts
Views: No views
Title: Bird Flys to Wherever You Point to
Views: 717K views
Title: A group of migratory birds arranged in a heart shape
Views: 11K views
Title: Dogs walk, but birds fly. Therefore God?
Views: 1.1M views
Title: You count how many birds fly and comment
Views: 2K views
Title: Why do birds fly south? #comedy #dadjokes
Views: 1.6K views
Title: Why do Birds fly in a V?|BS Chandra Mohan |Mlife Daily #shorts
Views: 115K views
Title: wow je is so lucky but when we walk the birds fly away and no one gives us attention.
Views: No views
Title: birds fly #calmness #youtube #shorts #video
Views: No views
Title: birds fly they don't lie
Views: 112 views
Title: Thiruvanmiyur beach | birds fly #yuvan #birdsfly #shorts
Views: No views
Title: beautiful pigeons and his egg/Birds/fly birds/beauty of birds/nature/funny/viral videos/status video
Views: 1 view
Title: Group of Birds fly in one spot
Views: 63 views
Title: Bird falls #learningtofly #birds #fly
Views: 1.4K views
Title: Dove bird unfortunately trapped in my house #birds #fly #dovebird #happybhinder❤️
Views: 1.8K views
Title: pet birds @Fly love youtube #bird #ytshorts #shirts
Views: No views
Title: baby birds fly
Views: No views
Title: Birds Fly in the sky because.....#shorts #facts #subscribe #birds #sky
Views: No views
Title: How Birds Fly❓ #shorts #DeepNature
Views: No views
Title: “A bird never wants a cage.” #birds #fly #viral #shorts #youtubeshorts #shortvideo #hiamazingindia
Views: No views
Title: Birds fly in different directions 
Views: 146 views
Title: baby bird try to get fly p44 #shorts
Views: 5.8K views
Title: smallest eggs @Fly Love #youtube #birds #bird #shorts
Views: 1.7K views
Title: african birds@ Fly Love #youtube #love #trend #sound #shortsvideo #shorts
Views: 164 views
Title: african birds @Fly love #youtube #birds #fly #food #shirts #africa #africanbirs
Views: 60 views
Title: Pets Birds @Fly love #youtube #birds #shorts #arbic #song
Views: 86 views
Title: african colourful birds @Fly Love youtube #bird #youtube #ytshorts #trend #sound #shorts
Views: 139 views
Title: Trying to make the baby birds fly
Views: 228 views
Title: see how birds fly together #shorts #birdsfly #together
Views: No views

Number of shorts: 40
```